# Protractor right approach to page object model

Tags: test-automation-framework, protractor, page-objects

On Investigating on protractor page object model, i came across the below two approaches:

**First:**

```js
var AngularHomepage = function() {
   var nameInput = element(by.model('yourName'));
   var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

   this.get = function() {
      browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
   };

   this.setName = function(name) {
      nameInput.sendKeys(name);
   };

   this.getGreetingText = function() {
      return greeting.getText();
   };
};
module.exports = new AngularHomepage();
```

**Second**

```js
'use strict';  

module.exports = {  
    toDo: {  
        addField: element(by.css('[placeholder="add new todo here"]')),  
        checkedBox: element(by.model('todo.done')),  
        addButton: element(by.css('[value="add"]'))  
    },  

    go: function() {  
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org/'); //overrides baseURL  
        browser.waitForAngular();  
    },  

    addItem: function(item) {  
        var todo = this.toDo;  

        todo.addField.isDisplayed();  
        todo.addField.sendKeys(item);  
        todo.addButton.click();  
    }  
};
```

The second approach looked more clean and looked promising, could someone suggest which one should i go for. If you have any additional styles , please do help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never really used protractor, but I built some tests in JavaScript. I would prefer the second one, as it does not have this this this everywhere. I think it is more readable.

You can also wrap it in a function again to make it a bit more descriptive, and so you can include a sort of private methods.

I structured my JavaScript tests like this:

```js
const browser = constructBrowser();
const MyPage = require('./pagename.pageobject.js')({ browser });

it('test MyPage', () => {
  MyPage.open();
  MyPage.action();
});
```

pagename.pageobject.js:

```js
module.exports = function Page(options) {
  if (!options.browser) throw Error('options.browser is required');
  const { browser } = options;

  const nav = By.className('nav');
  const button = By.className('btn');
  const url = 'http://server/';

  return {
    open: () => {
      browser.get(url);
    },
    action: () => {
      browser.findElement(nav).click();
      privateFnc();
    },
  };

  function privateFnc() {
      browser.findElement(btn).click();
  };
};
```

Have a look at my project at Github: https://github.com/nreijmersdal/stoppable/tree/master/test/integration

Comment: Hi would there be  any need of private functions in page object ?

Comment: Sure, I like to break down everything in short functions. The top return object will contain all the actions on the page. While the implementation sits in private functions. But it is not nececary, but i think it feels cleaner :)

Comment: Hi when you wrapp it again with a function , it will become same like first implementation right ? .